# Question regarding Object Oriented PHP with the syntax involved

Tags: php, oop

I'm following Aleana's videos through OOP, I understand the concepts of the keyword $this, self etc but when she refers to $this->property_name->method_name(); I get confused.

Is this saying we are passing the property to the method? My description is where she returns $this->current()->details

Example code below:

```
public function shortDescription()
{
    if(strlen($this->current()->details) < 510){
        return strip_tags($this->current()->details);
    }
}
```

Any help on helping me understand it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is called method chaining

Comment: thanks very much, I wasn't to sure on the terminology so thanks for pointing me in that direction.